# Solve for c for the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

What are the values of c that satisfy the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals for $ y= \frac{5^{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x} $ in [1,4].

I arrived to a simpler equation

$$ \frac{40}{3ln5} = \frac{5^{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x} $$

Other forums say there is no solution for this problem, but I graphed it in Demos and found that 2.59... is a point of intersection of the equation within the said interval. So, I concluded that c is approximately 2.59. Can someone prove or disprove this?

Comment: It's time to break out a numerical algorithm.

Comment: `Mathematica` says: $\frac{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{40} \ln ^2(5)\right){}^2}{\ln^2(5)}\approx 2.59$ where: $W$ is LambertW function.